# Knockout.js calling method outside of view model

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, highcharts

I want to make my data accessible outside of my view model. So I created a view model object but I'm having trouble binding its properties. Note that everything is working properly inside my view model.

Basically a simplified pseudo-code:

```
function Users() {
    name;
    date;
}

function userHealthModel() {
     function createUsers() { new Users[] };
}

self.userModel = ko.observable(new userHealthModel());
self.userModel.createUsers();
```

If I call the `createUsers` method inside my model my bind works fine.

Here is a jsFiddle, note my problem is all the way at the end of the JS, I commented it:
http://jsfiddle.net/fourgates/jpk22/1/

I'm new to JS and KO. not really sure how to use $root, $parent, etc. Please help a fellow programming enthusiast! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask a specific question instead of posting just a big bunch of code that somehow "does not work". You got already a lot set up, so where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: im sorry please excuse my laziness i was very tired when i wrote this, just took a nap. i rewrote my question with a jsfiddle. 

but basically im having trouble binding properties of a viewModel object i made, outside of my view model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but here are some thoughts about the code in your fiddle:

If you have something like

```
var self = this;
```

in the global scope (= not in a function), `this` points to the window object. Therefore this does not make any sense.

```
self.userModel = ko.observable(new userHealthModel());
```

Creating an observable of a view model is not necessary - you don't expect the whole model to change, right? It will always stay a user model and not suddenly become a "message model" or whatever.

If you want to call a method of your view model from the outside, just make an instance:

```
var userModel = new userHealthModel();
userModel.createUsers();

// Use "userModel" to access the methods and properties
// like you're using "self" inside the view model:
userModel.users2()[1].userId(5);

// now apply the binding to THE SAME view model
ko.applyBindings(userModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpk22/3/

If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know!

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i was trying to do! that makes sense that the model would not be observable. Thank you very much for the help!